# Using rxjs withLatestFrom in correct way

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 pages (page X and page Y). They both share the same component and resolver.

In `ngOnInit()` of the shared component, I use the `route.queryParams` and `route.data`:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.route.data),
    map(([qp, data]: [Params, Data]) => {

    }),
  );
}
```

Also, note, that for both pages I've defined in the `routing` the following: `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'`. Means, that the resolver will be activated also when navigate between pages that share the same component.

Now - the probelm is when I navigate from page X to Y or vice versa.
The problem is with `withLatestFrom`.
When I move to the second page, the `data` I get in `map(([qp, data]: [Params, Data]) => {...})` **is equal to the data that the resolver gave for entering the first page** - But I need the data the resolver would give for second page.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `this.route.queryParams` emits before `this.route.data` emits on a route change. If you want to emit after both observables have emitted since the last emit use `zip`.

```ts
zip(this.route.queryParams, this.route.data).pipe(
  map(([qp, data]: [Params, Data]) => {

  }),
);
```